# Problem with Xubuntu Terminal theme colors

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

After messing around with GIT I noticed that my terminal lost most of it's text colors and after installing many different themes, the text color's won't come back. The only thing I can change is background and a few other options...

I did try installing new themes, deleting terminalrc, restarting, reseting terminal to factory defaults, etc.

Here's a related pic:
[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBlUe.png)

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was search for .bashrc themes, and not a full xfce theme.
Now it looks better :D